# Tensorflow Out of Memory when saving?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I'm running the Linux CPU version of tensorflow on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm running out of memory when I try to save my model. I'm using the tutorial for Deep MNIST that builds a convolution network. You can find it here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#deep-mnist-for-experts

I changed a couple of things and tried to add a Saver to export the model weights. However when I run it I get an error that says I am out of memory. Which doesn't make sense to me because it can train the data forever but saving it somehow uses too much memory?

```
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
step 0, training accuracy 0.06
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:909] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10000,28,28,32]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mgump/Lambda_Project/MNIST_TRAINER.py", line 66, in <module>
x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 555, in eval
return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3498, in  _eval_using_default_session
return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10000,28,28,32]    
[[Node: Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME",  strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true,   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape, Variable/read)]]
Caused by op u'Conv2D', defined at:
File "/home/mgump/Lambda_Project/MNIST_TRAINER.py", line 28, in <module>
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
File "/home/mgump/Lambda_Project/MNIST_TRAINER.py", line 18, in conv2d
return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 394, in conv2d
data_format=data_format, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()`
```

This is what it outputs when I run it thanks so much!

Comment: It looks like you're using a very large batch size (10000). Something more like 500 is probably appropriate. A 10000 * 28 * 28 * 32 tensor will take ~1Gb of RAM.